# Would it be correct to use “它” in a sentence like this "它在外面下雪了."？

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Just as the title says, would it be correct to use “它” in a sentence like this "它在外面下雪了." or I could just say "在外面下雪了"？

Comment: it would definitely be wrong, "it was snowing outside" is OP's 2nd choice, see grammar on subjectless sentences, especially those indicating weather conditions

Comment: "It is snowing outside" in Chinese is just  "外面正在下雪" ( snowing outside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "it" in "it is snowing" does not refer to anything. It is there because a subject is needed in a declarative sentence in English. Chinese, however, is different in that subjectless declarative sentences are perfectly fine. When we try to translate a sentence such as "it is snowing", it's best to simply ignore the "it". You won't lose anything semantically.

It is snowing.  下雪了.

It is snowing outside. 外面下雪了.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct. 
The correct sentence is

> 外面（在）下雪

In Chinese, as in some other European languages, weather verbs have **zero valency**, which means that they take no arguments, neither object nor subject. Therefore you must omit `它`.

Comment: 什么时候在房子里下雪？。为什么不说‘下雪’？：-）如果也说’外面‘，你还认为’下雪‘是’零价‘的？

Comment: 《外面》是处所补语，跟述语配价无关

Comment: 如果是这样的为什么用来？你如何定义’述语‘了吗？

Answer (score 1):

In English, 'it' refers to 'weather' in "it's snowing outside."

In Chinese, we interpret this 'it' as '天', since 天 could refer to 天气（weather） in this setting.

We say:

> (外面)天正在下雨 // it's raining outside
>
> (外面)天正在下雪 // it's snowing outside
>
> (外面)天正在刮风 // it's windy outside
>
> 今天，天（气/儿）很好！ // today, the whether is good!

However, 天 could be omitted most of time. They will become:

> 外面正在下雨 // it's raining outside
>
> 外面正在下雪 // it's snowing outside
>
> 外面正在刮风 // it's windy outside
>
> 今天，天（气/儿）很好！ // in this case, 天 can not be omitted. Otherwise, there is no clue for what subject is being talked.

Your issue with 它在外面下雪了 is:

> 1. you should replace 它 with 天。
> 2. 外面 is used as adv or adj, so 外面 itself is ok. No need 在.
> 3. the sentence order; you could consider 外面 as 外面(的)天， so 天(S) + 下雪(V)+ 了(C) . 外面（的） serves as an adj. to modify 天. So, either 外面(的)天下雪了 or 外面下雪了 works.